# Criando uma linha de comando com vários argumentos usando DSharpPlus?

Tags: c#

Estou começando a programar em C# e como projeto pessoal estou criando um Bot para Discord de rolagem de dados utilizando o `DSharpPlus`.

Meu problema está em como fazer para identificar os **argumentos** (*não sei se estou usando o termo correto*) no comando digitado no Discord.

Exemplos:

```
/roll 6 -dif 5 -esp
```

Quando digito `/roll 6` tenho o retorno de seis números gerados pelo Bot. (consegui chegar até aqui)

Mas o que quero é que quando digitasse `-dif 5` por exemplo, eu teria o retorno de quantos resultados estão acima ou abaixo do `5` nesse caso.

E no caso do `-esp` preciso que o Bot apenas reconheça se esse argumento está ou não no comando para que eu coloque numa variável *booleana*. Os métodos e classes para ter esses resultados eu já escrevi, só não consigo fazer a conexão entre meu código e o Bot.

Esse é o comando que escrevi até agora para executar o comando `/roll` no Discord.

```
[Command("roll")]
[Aliases("r")]
public async Task Rolagem(CommandContext ctx, int dado)
{
    Dados jogada = new Dados();
    jogada.Rolagem(dado);

    var janela = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
    {
        Title = "Resultado",
        Color = DiscordColor.DarkRed,
        Description = $"Rolagem: {jogada.ExibirResultado}"                
    };

    await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(embed: janela).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: acho que nesse caso pode ser um *array* de parametros, por exemplo `Rolagem(CommandContext ctx, string[] parametros)`

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu faria para que cada item do *array* seja preenchido com o trecho específico do comando dado no Discord?